# How to adapt a C++-style random number engine for GSL (GNU Scientific Library)?

Tags: c++, random, gsl

I have a PRNG that satisfies the requirements of a C++ random number engine, as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberEngine). (It's from the [PCG family](http://www.pcg-random.org)). That is, an instance of the engine can be used by C++ standard library distribution classes to generate random numbers:

```
pcg_extras::seed_seq_from<std::random_device> seed_source;
pcg32 rng(seed_source);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniformDist(0., 1.);
double randomNumber = uniformDist(rng);
```

I need to generate samples from a distribution not included in `<random>`, so I need to use a function from GSL. How do I use my C++ engine for this purpose? The GSL rng functions all require a `const gsl_rng *` as the first argument.

The default creation and usage of `gsl_rng` is as follows:

```
const gsl_rng_type * T;
gsl_rng * r;
gsl_rng_env_setup();
T = gsl_rng_default;
r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
double u = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
```

To use my own engine, I believe that I will need to define a `gsl_rng_type`, as defined in `"gsl/gsl_rng.h"`:

```
typedef struct
  {
    const char *name;
    unsigned long int max;
    unsigned long int min;
    size_t size;
    void (*set) (void *state, unsigned long int seed);
    unsigned long int (*get) (void *state);
    double (*get_double) (void *state);
  }
gsl_rng_type;
```

Am I correct in what I surmise is needed? Are there examples out there of how I might define a custom `gsl_rng_type`, especially the three necessary member functions? What might be my `void *state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following to get things working. Note that my random number engine is a global variable in my program: `g_rng`.

It's necessary to construct a struct to hold whatever state is relevant for the RNG. In my case, I simply hold a pointer to `pcg32`:

```
// In some header file, e.g. rng.h
typedef struct
{
    pcg32 *rng;
} gsl_pcg_state;
```

Three functions, "set", "get", and "get_double" must be defined:

```
// In some header file, e.g. rng.h
static void gsl_pcg_set(void *state, unsigned long int seed)
{
    ((gsl_pcg_state *)state)->rng = &g_rng;
    (void)seed;                 // unused
}

static unsigned long int gsl_pcg_get(void *state)
{
    return (*((gsl_pcg_state *)state)->rng)();
}

static double gsl_pcg_get_double(void *state)
{
    // Range [0, 1)
    return (*((gsl_pcg_state *)state)->rng)() / 4294967296.;
}
```

So then a `gsl_rng_type` can be instantiated:

```
static const gsl_rng_type gsl_rng_pcg = {
    "pcg",
    0xffffffffUL,
    0,
    sizeof(gsl_pcg_state),
    &gsl_pcg_set,
    &gsl_pcg_get,
    &gsl_pcg_get_double
};
```

Within the main program, you would have...

```
gsl_rng *r;
r = gsl_rng_alloc(&gsl_rng_pcg);
// one can now call various gsl_ran_[...] functions

gsl_rng_free(r);
```

Looking at `gsl_rng_alloc` as defined in `rng.c` from GSL confirms this is the right setup.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The entire public interface is outlined in https://github.com/LuaDist/gsl/blob/master/rng/gsl_rng.h